# How to add & build a typescript file in ASP.net web application under Visual studio 2012?

Tags: asp.net, typescript

After installing "TypeScript 1.0 Tools for Visual Studio 2012",
Typescript file can be added & built under [HTML Application with TypeScript].
However, it doesn't work under ASP.NET Web application.

And, if I add a .js file and rename it as a .ts file, I can't find TypescriptCompile
under build Action.
Do I miss some important setting or need to modify the project file?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the project file. Here is a sample section:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>true</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>false</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
</PropertyGroup>
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

Comment: I haven't tried it VB.NET. Personally I compile outside Visual Studio using https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts just because it works with notepad ;) You might want to report it with a sample e.g. there was https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1850

Comment: @coder VS2013 has a much better TypeScript project option settings dialog (again only tried C# though)